# Can't add selector for all matching choices in Dymola

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, dymola

I was following the tutorial from Claytex at https://www.claytex.com/blog/dymola-basics-8-dymola-model-inheritance/ on partial and extended models. I'm able to create an inherited (extended) model from a parent (partial) model, and it allows me to change between sibling classes. However, I want to add the box selector for all sibling classes as shown in the tutorial

[image]

Here's my code

Model 'a'

```
partial model a
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Interfaces.HeatPort_a port_a annotation (
      Placement(transformation(rotation=0, extent={{-110,-10},{-90,10}})));
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Interfaces.HeatPort_b port_b annotation (
      Placement(transformation(rotation=0, extent={{90,-10},{110,10}})));
  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="3.2.3")), Icon(graphics={Text(
          extent={{-100,102},{98,-98}},
          lineColor={28,108,200},
          textString="A")}));
end a;
```

Model 'b'

```
model b
  extends a;

  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components.ThermalResistor thermalResistor(R=3)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}})));

equation 
  connect(port_a, thermalResistor.port_a)
    annotation (Line(points={{-100,0},{-10,0}}, color={191,0,0}));
  connect(port_b, thermalResistor.port_b)
    annotation (Line(points={{100,0},{10,0}}, color={191,0,0}));


  annotation (Icon(graphics={Text(
          extent={{26,96},{98,12}},
          lineColor={28,108,200},
          textString="B")}));
end b;
```

Model 'assembly'

```
model assembly
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sources.FixedTemperature fixedTemperature(T=274.15)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-60,40},{-40,60}})));
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sources.FixedTemperature fixedTemperature1(T=275.15)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{40,40},{20,60}})));
  replaceable b a1 constrainedby a annotation (choicesAllMatching=true, Placement(transformation(extent={
            {-20,40},{0,60}})));
equation 
  connect(fixedTemperature.port, a1.port_a)
    annotation (Line(points={{-40,50},{-20,50}}, color={191,0,0}));
  connect(a1.port_b, fixedTemperature1.port)
    annotation (Line(points={{0,50},{20,50}}, color={191,0,0}));
  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="3.2.3")));
end assembly;
```

I'd appreciate if someone can point out where my implementation is different from the tutorial. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That should work in itself (assuming all classes are public) in Dymola, but to get the box selector you either need to click in the background of `assembly` diagram or create a TopModel using it as in the Tutorial and then bring up the parameter dialog for `assembly1`

```
model TopModel
  assembly assembly1
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-40,20},{-20,40}})));
  annotation (Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)), Diagram(
        coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)));
end TopModel;
```

Additionally partial classes are filtered out from the selector so you only get b in it unless you also add:

```
model c
  extends a;

  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components.ThermalResistor thermalResistor(R=3)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}})));

equation 
  connect(port_a, thermalResistor.port_a)
    annotation (Line(points={{-100,0},{-10,0}}, color={191,0,0}));
  connect(port_b, thermalResistor.port_b)
    annotation (Line(points={{100,0},{10,0}}, color={191,0,0}));

  annotation (Icon(graphics={Text(
          extent={{26,96},{98,12}},
          lineColor={28,108,200},
          textString="C")}));
end c;
```

I had all of these classes within one package `P`. Note that the selector may take a few second to open the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me (Dymola 2023x)

1. I can right click `a1`, select `Change Class` --> `All Matching Choices` and select model `b` (or `c` which is just a copy of `b`).
   [image]
2. I can open the Parameters dialog for `assembly` (right click the modelling canvas and click `Parameters`) and select `b` or `c` in the dropdown menu next to `a1`.
   [image]